# R tm removeWords stopwords is not removing stopwords

Tags: r, nlp, stop-words, tm

I'm using the R tm package, and find that almost none of the `tm_map` functions that remove elements of text are working for me.

By 'working' I mean for example, I'll run:

```
d <- tm_map(d, removeWords, stopwords('english'))
```

but then when I run

```
ddtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(d, control = list(
    weighting = weightTfIdf,
    minWordLength = 2))
findFreqTerms(ddtm, 10)
```

I still get:

```
[1] the     this
```

...etc., and a bunch of other stopwords.

I see no error indicating something has gone wrong.  Does anyone know what this is, and how to make stopword-removal function correctly, or diagnose what's going wrong for me?

**UPDATE**

There is an error earlier up that I didn't catch:

```
Refreshing GOE props...
---Registering Weka Editors---
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): RmiJdbc.RJDriver - Warning, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): jdbc.idbDriver - Warning, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver - Warning, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): com.mckoi.JDBCDriver - Warning, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver - Warning, not in CLASSPATH?
[KnowledgeFlow] Loading properties and plugins...
[KnowledgeFlow] Initializing KF...
```

It is Weka that is removing stopwords in tm, right?  So this could be my problem?

**Update 2**

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720229/help-with-adding-the-database-drivers-inorder-to-use-weka-classes), this error appears to be unrelated.  It's about the db, not about stopwords.

Comment: have you tried what they suggest here: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-February/302479.html ?

Comment: Thanks, but that looks like that would just suppress my error messages, not help weka find the file, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nevermind, it is working.  I did the following minimum example:

```
data("crude")
crude[[1]]
j <- Corpus(VectorSource(crude[[1]]))
jj <- tm_map(j, removeWords, stopwords('english'))
jj[[1]]
```

I had used several `tm_map` expressions in series.  It turned out, the order that I had removed spaces, punctuation, etc, had concatenated new stopwords back in.

Comment: Yes it can be devilish to get those `tm_map` functions in the right order. I've struggled with stemming in the past and found reordering the sequence to help. Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: I have basically the same problem with custom words in removeWords. What was the order supposed to be? I'm running stripWhitepace, removePunctuation, removeWords, and stemDocument. I'll figure it out I suppose, but perhaps it would be worth updating the solution with the correct order.